# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in header.php on line 187

Tags: php

I am facing this problem in my `header.php` file.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in `header.php` on line 187

Here is code can anyone please tell me where is syntax missing.

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail("featured", array("class" => "alignleft"));                        
?>
```

Comment: you opened `{` in if condition but where is `}` braces ?

Comment: I added this but its not working

Comment: What do your functions contain?

Comment: How Can I send full file ?

Comment: Use the edit button possibly; how large is the file?

Comment: Its not letting me put full file

Comment: Okay, what is happening now? Same error? These are usually just typos and require you to just double check that indentations match up.

Comment: Same error you can check full file here
http://wikisend.com/download/470178/header.php

Comment: Post it on eval.in, or some sandbox site.

Comment: Are you able to see full file ?

Comment: No, I'm not downloading a file to my system.

Comment: Here you can see
https://eval.in/480223

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing `}`.

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail("featured", array(
        "class" => "alignleft"
    ));
}
?>
```

Comment: @johnsmith Still a syntax error? The code is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes still the syntax error only the line number change

Comment: Please send me the full file. I'll look into it. Might want to use http://wikisend.com/

Comment: How Can I send full file ?

Comment: http://wikisend.com/ @johnsmith

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/470178/header.php

Comment: Ok, looking into it.

Comment: You have lots of syntax errors... What did you mean by this:`<?php 
                    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                             if($number2 == 0){
                                $active = "active";
                             }else{
                                $active = "";
                            }
                         ?>`

Comment: Looks like chaos, good luck in the rabbit hole you are about to enter.

Comment: Can you please solve it. I did not write it Remove unnecessary codes Thanks

Comment: Why it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

missing `}`

```
<?php 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                           the_post_thumbnail("featured", array("class" => "alignleft"));
                       }

                       endwhile;  
                       endif;
                   }
                       ?>
```

Comment: post other code too...

Comment: how Can I post full file here ?

Comment: alteast line till line 187

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/470178/header.php
Please take a look at full file

Comment: update the answer but your header.php code is not complete.

Comment: It worked but not completely header is not showing correctly
Thanks qaisar

Comment: @johnsmith if this help kindly accept the answer.

Comment: it not completely help qiasar site is showing now but header is too bad

Comment: but what is in ur header was before there are some html code are missing and it is not in your file so can't help on there.

Comment: how it should be miss when it was working fine

Comment: as you can see there is carsoul added in while loop but the item code is missing..

Comment: How we can find the carsoul code ?

Answer (score 0):

In your file there are two braces missing.

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){  ?>  // one closing brace `}` missing for this if condition. **give spaces here**...

 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  // one closing brace `}` for this if condition
```

So at end of your page you have to add two closing braces. update your code like this:

```
 <?php 
     if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
       the_post_thumbnail("featured", array("class" => "alignleft")); 
     }
 }
?>     

query_posts(array("category_name" => "Home Slider" , "post_per_page" => -1, "showposts" => -1 , "post_type" => "post"));
if(have_posts()):  endif;  /// add here endif;

while(have_posts()): the_post(); endwhile;  /// add here endwhile;
```

Comment: arse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Comment: please give space `<?php if(is_front_page())  {  ?>` at this statement and check.

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not working

Comment: now check my updated answer.

Comment: really appreciate your help but it is still showing the same error